# Deploy android application on multuple devices

Tags: android, deployment, installation

recently, we have developed an android application. And now, we're looking for a way to deploy this app on 60 devices automatically. is that possible ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute the apk file to each device or publish your app to google play store.
But when you say "deploy automatically", you mean what?

Comment: Questions about clarification of the OP should be comments.